# Перемещение списка к нужному Toggle (Unity3D, Toggle, c #)

Tags: c#, unity3d, список, toggle

У меня есть список состоящий из Toggle(12 шт), чтобы пользователь видел, что ему нужно еще сделать или сделано, как список дел. Как выделить определенный toggle в списке, чтобы он видел, что действие сделано. Например выполнил он верно, список переместился туда, где видно нужный(например 10ый) toggle

Сам список по сути из двух элементов. Image(ScrollArea) со свойствами Mask, ScrollRect и второй image(Content) со свойствами Content Size Filter, Vertical Laouy Group и дочерние уже toggl-ы идут. Если эта информация необходима

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вариантов несколько.

1. Очевидный, но мною забытый - создание массива объектов и менять индексы в нужном порядке. Гуглим массивы и функции
2. Довольно странный, но рабочий(мой конечный вариант в проекте) - использование "name_obj[indext_obj].**transform.SetSiblingIndex**(index);" для перемещения в иерархии объектов(лист-рукав слева в редакторе юнити по дефолту), создаем массив и меняем с помощью его порядок